# Redirect to another view using AJAX call in Codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

My table contains many rows from database. After clicking edit button in a row, I want to redirect it to another page. I am able get the data, but it cannot redirect to the other page.

I'm using bootstrap template, so there are different file to load on view. I do not know how to load view that consist of more than one files.

**Ajax**

```
$('#example2').on('click','#edit',function(){
    var id_per = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
    alert("ini"+id_per);
    $.ajax({
        url:"<?php echo base_url('c_dokter/ubahdt_perawatan/');?>" + id_per,
        type:"POST",
        data:{
            id_perawatan : id_per,
            id_pasien : id_pasien
        },
        dataType:'JSON',
        success:function(data) {
    },
    error:function() {
        alert('error ... ');
    }
});
```

**Controller**

```
public function ubahdt_perawatan($id_perawatan){
    $data['pasien']=$this->m_pasien->spes_Perawatan($id_perawatan);
    if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
        echo json_encode($data);
        exit;
    }
    $data['pasien']=$this->m_pasien->DataPerPasien($id_pasien)->result();
    $data['sidebar']='member/dokter/sidebar_psn';
    $data['content']='member/dokter/edit_perawatan';
    $this->load->view('member/dokter/main',$data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited answer:

```
 public function ubahdt_perawatan($id_perawatan){
        $data['pasien']=$this->m_pasien->spes_Perawatan($id_perawatan);
        if ($this->input->is_ajax_request())
            {
              echo json_encode($data); 
            }


}

public function test()
{
     $id_pasien=$this->uri->segment(2);
      $data['pasien']=$this->m_pasien->DataPerPasien($id_pasien)->result();

        $this->load->view('member/dokter/sidebar_psn');
         $this->load->view('member/dokter/edit_perawatan');
        $this->load->view('member/dokter/main',$data);
}
```

set path to test() in routes.php..

```
$route['test/(:any)']='controller/test';
```

then in ajax success function

```
success:function(data){
window.location.href="<?php echo site_url('test/'.data);";

        },
```

try it.

Comment: it redirect to 404 page not found

Comment: what is your view? main.php ?? didi you set route

Comment: like this  "  $route['test']='contriollername/test';  "   in roures.php

Comment: in which part of route.php I can set it?

Comment: how do you normally set path in routes

Comment: I think it work, but after I set the path, the new problem appear. how can I pass the parameter from ajax to test(), because in test() it also call model function with parameter from ajax

Comment: it work but it redirect to page with no sidebar, and the page (edit_perawatan)  only display it first row

Comment: i think they are views, i've edited my answer. check it

Comment: main consist of header and footer, side_bar is the menu on the side, and the edit perawatan is the main page

Comment: it still erorr in console, I try this window.location.href="<?php echo site_url('test')?>";
          window.location.href=data; but it say The URI you submitted has disallowed characters. Can you help me why this happen?